# Цитирование в Телеграм бот PHP

Tags: php, telegram-bot

ребята, у меня телеграм бот реагирует на слова в чате-

```
    function processMessage($message) {
  // process incoming message
  $message_id = $message['message_id'];
  $chat_id = $message['chat']['id'];
  if (isset($message['text'])) {
    // incoming text message
    $text = $message['text'];
if (preg_match("/\bБилеты\b/ui", $text)){
apiRequest("sendMessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "text" => 'Билеты есть на числа 1,2,3'));
    }
```

НО я хочу чтобы он отвечал не просто в чат, а именно цитированием (reply), изменил вод на вот такой-

```
    function processMessage($message) {
  // process incoming message
  $message_id = $message['message_id'];
  $chat_id = $message['chat']['id'];
  if (isset($message['text'])) {
    // incoming text message
    $text = $message['text'];
$update = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

if($update->message->text == 'мир'){
     bot('sendMessage',[
       'chat_id'=>$update->message->chat->id,
       'text'=>'Привет мир!',
       'reply_to_message_id' => $update->message->message_id
     ]);
}
```

ничего не работает(((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первом участке кода у вас взаимодействие идет через функцию `apiRequest("sendMessage`

```
apiRequest("sendMessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "text" => 'Билеты есть на числа 1,2,3'));
```

Во втором через `bot('sendMessage`

```
if($update->message->text == 'мир'){
     bot('sendMessage',[
       'chat_id'=>$update->message->chat->id,
       'text'=>'Привет мир!',
       'reply_to_message_id' => $update->message->message_id
     ]);
}
```

Скорее всего вы этот код скопировали с соседней ветки, поэтому попробуйте

```
if($update->message->text == 'мир'){
     apiRequest('sendMessage', [
       'chat_id'=>$update->message->chat->id,
       'text'=>urlencode('Привет мир!'),
       'reply_to_message_id' => $update->message->message_id
     ]);
}
```

Comment: да вы правы пробелмы была в этом) сейчас все работает, единственное я не понял зачем вы предложили 'text'=>urlencode  из за него идут кразощябры вместо русского текста. я сделал без него.

Comment: @ГеоргийКовалев не знаю, всегда использую и проблем с кодировкой нет никаких, наоборот они бывают когда не использую)

Comment: посмотрите вот это? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1080483/restrictchatmember-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-php-%d0%a2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0