# restrictChatMember для php Телеграм бота

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

ребята, есть у меня скриптик с помощью которго бот в чате отслеживает ключевые слова, сообщает пользователю что это спам, удаляет его пост, а я хочу еще и третий этап туда добаить- ограничение в написании постов в чат на N-ое заданное время.  МУТ на час допустим.  как это дописать? не смог найти в инете примеров restrictChatMember на РНР.
вот мой код-

```
    function processMessage($message) {
  $message_id = $message['message_id'];
  $chat_id = $message['chat']['id'];
  if (isset($message['text'])) {
    $text = $message['text'];

// против спама
$update = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
if(preg_match("/\b(ВАСЯ|ФЕДЯ)\b/ui", $update->message->text)){
     apiRequest('sendMessage', [
       'chat_id'=>$update->message->chat->id,
       'text'=>'Это спам!',
       'reply_to_message_id' => $update->message->message_id
     ]);
sleep(1);
apiRequest('deleteMessage', [
       'chat_id'=>$update->message->chat->id,
       'message_id' => $update->message->message_id
     ]);
// далее ставим мут пользователю, я это вижу примерно так но прошу поправить синтаксис-
apiRequest('restrictChatMember', [
       'chat_id'=>$update->message->chat->id,
       'user_id' => $update->message->user_id,
'ChatPermissions' => can_send_messages=FALSE, can_send_media_messages=false, can_send_polls=false, can_send_other_messages=false,
'until_date' => КАКОЕ то время
     ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно `chatPermissions` следует указать массивом

```
apiRequest('restrictChatMember', [
       'chat_id' => $update->message->chat->id,
       'user_id' => $update->message->user_id,
       'chatPermissions' => ['can_send_messages' => false, 'can_send_media_messages' => false, 'can_send_polls' => false, 'can_send_other_messages' => false],
       'until_date' => time() + 3600
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'permissions' => json_encode(array('can_send_messages' => false, 'can_invite_users' => true))
```

разрешения прописываются следующим образом